# Como mostrar una alerta con el nombre del usuario js obteniendo la SESSION de php

Tags: javascript, php

Hola buen dia quiero que me muestre una alerta de js con el nombre del usuario que se logeo,

he intentado lo siguiente

PHP:

```
$usuario = $_SESSION['identity'];
```

js:

```
var mostrarUser = "<?php echo $usuario ?>";
alert(mostrarUser);
```

me imprime como un texto `<?php echo $usuario ?>` y no obtengo el nombre del usario

hay otra forma de obtner la variable de php y mostrarlo en js

Comment: Tienes un par de opciones para conseguirlo. 1) Si creas ese javascript desde el PHP debería funcionar lo que has puesto, por lo que entiendo que no lo creas desde allí y por eso no te funciona.  2) Usando ajax y realizando la consulta a un PHP que te devuelva ese resultado esperado.

Comment: PHP y JS son **dos universos distintos**, aquel está del lado del servidor, éste del lado del cliente. Si quieres comunicar entre ellos usa Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript.

Comment: @masterguru gracias por responder, una idea de como crearlo con ajax

Comment: @Max Por un lado crea un archivo simple en PHP que empiece con `session_start();` y que devuelva el valor de esa sesión con un echo, por ejemplo, `echo $_SESSION['identity'];` y nada más.  Y por el otro, aprende el uso de ajax (hay miles de ejemplos por la red, preferentemente con jQuery te será más facil) o de [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) como sugiere @A.Cedano, para lanzar ese PHP y recoger el dato para ponerlo en el alert().  No podemos hacerlo por tí, pero si lo intentas y no te sale lo pones en la pregunta y te ayudamos.

Comment: vale gracias por sus respuestas, si tengo alguna duda les notificare, excelente día